# How to get pos/neg instance counts for all nodes of a scikit-learn decision tree?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I've trained a sklearn decision tree.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
c=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight="auto")
c.fit([[0,0],
       [0,1],
       [1,1],
      ],[0,1,0])
```

Now I'd like to inspect how many positive/negative samples went to each node. Therefore a graph like

```
  counts: [2,1]            labels: (010)
                                 split by x0
    [1,1]       [1,0]         (01)        (0)
                           split by x1
 [1,0] [0,1]      0        (0)   (1)
   0     1
```

How can I get this (left counts) from a trained decision tree?

I can see a `c.tree_` variable, but the content seems not to be very helpful. There are zeros, weights, ... and it's hard to guess how to get the counts back.

Comment: Just the count values for each node. To create something like the pie charts in http://i.imgur.com/9WC72.png

Comment: I am still a bit confused about your desired output. Why the leaves in `counts` are labeled 1, 0, 1? The labels of samples are `[0, 1, 0]`. And why the root node is `[2, 1]` while its children are `[1, 1]` and `[0, 1]`?

Comment: You are right. I messed up the number. They are corrected now. But how can I make up for `class_weight`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of samples per class is stored in `tree_.value`, however it only stores node values for leaves, so I use post-order traverse to get values for all nodes.

```
import numpy as np

def get_value(dt):
    left = dt.tree_.children_left
    right = dt.tree_.children_right
    value = dt.tree_.value
    leaves = np.argwhere(left == -1)[:, 0]

    def visit(node):
        if node in leaves:
            return
        visit(left[node])
        visit(right[node])
        value[node, :] = value[left[node], :] + value[right[node], :]

    visit(0)
    return value
```

For example,

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt.fit([[0,0],
        [0,1],
        [1,1]], [0,1,0])
get_value(dt)
```

Out:

```
[[[ 2.  1.]]

 [[ 1.  1.]]

 [[ 1.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  1.]]

 [[ 1.  0.]]]
```

**Update #1**

I was wondering why the `tree_.value` only stores value for leaf nodes, then I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417809/show-values-at-each-node-level-of-scikit-learn-decision-tree and [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3958).

It turns out that in scikit-learn 0.17.dev0, `tree_.value` already returns values of all nodes.

```
In [1]: from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

In [2]: dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()

In [3]: dt.fit([[0,0],
   ...:         [0,1],
   ...:         [1,1]], [0,1,0])
Out[3]:
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            random_state=None, splitter='best')

In [4]: dt.tree_.value
Out[4]:
array([[[ 2.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.]]])
```

**Update #2**

Although I think it does **not** make sense to "undo the weighting" when `class_weight` is given, it is possible to achieve that.

The `class_weight` is computed by

```
In [1]: from sklearn.utils import compute_class_weight

In [2]: compute_class_weight('auto', [0, 1], [0, 1, 0])
Out[2]: array([ 0.66666667,  1.33333333])
```

So you can add `value[node, :] /= class_weight` after `if node in leaves:` to recompute the values of leaf nodes.

Comment: Looks good so far. How can I undo the weighting? If I use `class_weight="auto"` it changes the numbers somehow.

Comment: If `class_weight` is given, the values are weighted then. I don't think it makes sense to "undo the weighting". Perhaps you can neutralize the weight by re-weighting the leaf node according to the class it belongs to.

Comment: What would the re-weighting be in my example? I believe in my example I got 0.66 and 1.33 for unit size leaves. But I'm not sure how they relate to my class distribution exactly.

Comment: See my updates. I did not give complete example but hope you can understand.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `utils.compute_class_weight`.

Comment: It is no surprise since this function is not documented, but you can get help by `help(compute_class_weight)`